# Can I use different SQLSTATE codes for "unhandled user-defined exception" other than "45000"?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling

The question is about SIGNAL, like this:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Test error';
```

All the documentation and examples that I found only tells me that I can use the SQLSTATE "45000" to signal an "unhandled user-defined exception".

But can I use all the "45*" class for it?

For example can I signal "45001" for X situation, and "45002" for Y situation. It will help me to use conditions in the client application error handling.

I tested it and it works, seems that every "45*" is returning the error code 1644 and I can read the SQLSTATE from the exception and do my conditions.

But I cannot find any information that confirms it. Is it correct to do this? Is it permitted in MySQL?

If so, how much codes do I permitted to use? until 45999?

Comment: Have You read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html

Comment: @P.Salmon yes of course, but it only says "To signal a generic SQLSTATE value, use '45000', which means “unhandled user-defined exception.”", it not answers what I asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use whatever SQLSTATE you want in your application, with some conditions. The SQL standard specified `45---` as a dedicated subclass for user-thrown errors, although the standard doesn't prohibit from using other SQLSTATEs in the application code, as long as you follow the following:

1. The SQLSTATE you throw does have to be a **valid (well-formed)** SQLSTATE - that means, **exactly five bytes** with two first specifying a subclass (alphanumeric characters) and three next specifying the code within that subclass (only numbers). `45000`, `45001`, `39450`, `11037`, `AA439`, `FE041` are all valid SQLSTATEs (although not all of them counts as errors - subclasses beginning with `0` are *success* states, those beginning with `1` are non-breaking *warnings*, beginning with `2` are "X not found" conditions, while any first-byte value larger than `2` classifies as an error and terminates execution unless caught by a handler). On the other hand, `REEEE`, `G3,,,`, `DE0-1` are invalid SQLSTATEs, neither is i.e. `4500` (too short).
2. Avoid using SQLSTATEs already defined for something in the SQL standard specification outside of their original meaning - that could cause confusion during debugging. Keep a safe margin between *your* codes and *spec-defined* ones - the spec may potentially be updated by new SQLSTATEs defined in particular classes, and if no margin is kept, you'll be using spec-defined codes outside of their meaning.

A valid use case is to validate parameters or do in-procedure access control and throw exceptions on failures, when it's not enough to just return a well-known value and handle the situation in application code. In this case, you can even make a library of used SQLSTATEs, assign them to error messages in your application in a translatable resource, since the DB side will always return specified codes regardless of your users' locale.